# "Prisma Runtime Error: Cannot Read 'findMany' Properties from database in React App

Tags: next.js, prisma

Running to this error building a nextjs web app with prisma + mysql. All my other component files compile fine on run. I'm fairly new with this and been struggling to figure out. Code and error details below:

Code page.tsx:

```
import { Categories } from "@/components/categories";
import { SearchInput } from "@/components/search-input";
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";


const RootPage = async () => {
    const categories = await prismadb.category.findMany();
    return ( 
        <div className="h-full p-4 space-y-2">
            <SearchInput />
            <Categories data={categories} />
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default RootPage;
```

Error:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')

Source
app(root)(routes)\page.tsx (7:47) @ findMany

5 |
6 | const RootPage = async () => {

> 7 | const categories = await prismadb.category.findMany();
> |                                           ^
> 8 | return (
> 9 |     
> 10 |

Appreciate anyone's help and feedback.

The error suggests that there's an issue with accessing the findMany method - should be able to connect and return the category info from my db. What I Tried:

- Checked the Prisma schema definition for the Category model.
- Verified the database connection configuration through prisma studio
- Ensured that I'm using an asynchronous function and prisma db push to sync db schema
- Confirmed import statements for the Prisma client.

Comment: Update: Weird. I resaved my prismadb.ts file and things started to work - i didn't change anything.

Comment: i think you have to pass at least a empty object f.e. `findMany({})`